# Why is my text shifting to the left here?

Tags: css

I am trying to create a CSS Menu bar.

Here is [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ssF5K/8/)

Now, notice in the first menu item (Brushes) where I added `ul` and gave it class of `submenu`, the text shifts to the left. For the bottom two, its aligned in the middle. Why is this happening and how can I solve this problem?
I want all the menuItem text aligned in the middle even after adding subMenus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `width: 100%` to `.menuItems` may hurts the effects. Just Remove `width: inherit;` from `.menuItems a` selector.

**[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ssF5K/14/)**

Comment: Exactly What I wanted. Thanks a lot @HashemQolami

Answer (score 1):

Reason is `.menuItems` is not having a width of `100%`. If it is changed to `100%`, it works fine.

Here is the [WORKING SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/ssF5K/11/)

**The Code Change:**

```
.menuItems{
width: 100%;
}
```

Same goes with `.menuItems:hover`

Comment: Thanks for the answer again. But what if I do not want to have 100% width?

Comment: You're fighting table layout with widths. Much better to let this all be block level layout.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right, this helps you:

```
.menuItems a {
display: block;
line-height: 40px;
height: inherit;
width: inherit;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the "SUBMENU" element in page.
It take spase and push the brushes menu to left

try to resolve putting:

```
.menuItems{
width: 100%;
}
```

and

```
.menuItems:hover{
width: 110%; /*example*/
}
```

Hope was helpful...